# How to reinflate/change layout onConfigurationChanged while using ViewBinding?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

Generally, without using ViewBinding, I can removeAllViewsInLayout and then reinflate the landscape/portrait layout and do findViewById easily. How do I achieve something similar with ViewBinding?

I tried removing all views from ViewGroup and then inflating the layout but then the click(binding.button.setOnClick) won't work.

I have defined
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
to preserve state.